# List directory files in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, .net

I have searched many topics and can't find an answer on using the WPF `DataGrid` to list file name contents from a directory. I am able to output the contents in a `ListBox` but have no idea how to add items to a `Column` in `DataGrid`.

This works for a `ListBox`

```
string path = "C:";

object[] AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().ToArray();

foreach (object o in AllFiles)
{
    listbox.Items.Add(o.ToString());
}
```

How can I do the same with a `DataGrid`? Or atleast place `strings` from an `array` into a `DataGrid` `Column`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create `DataGrid` with one column:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding}" Header="Name"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and fill it in your code like this:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles();
```

By setting `ItemsSource` to `FileInfo[]` you have option to create other columns bound to other properties for `FileInfo` class. This `DataGrid` will work with any `IEnumerable` assigned to `ItemsSource`. If it won't be a `string` already then `ToString()` will be called

Comment: How can I bind data for a second column with a different source? If I use `Binding="{Binding}"`, the same information is displayed.

Comment: What do you mean by different source? Another property of `FileInfo` or another list of strings?

Comment: A different array that doesn't relate to `FileInfo`. I used the array for `ItemSource`. `myDataGrid.ItemsSource = AllFiles`; This works great. I was also able to call other values from different arrays. How can I add items from different arrays with information in different columns?

Comment: You cannot do that. Each `ItemsControl` can have only one source of items. You cannot have one column from one list and second from another. In this case you can only show different properties of `FileInfo` class as additional columns

Comment: It turns out that you can have different lists displaying in different columns. A solution is to create a `Class` with information for each column then `Binding` each column to the property from the `Class`. Of course, there would be logic to create a new instance of the `Class` for each row.

Answer (score 2):

You first have to add Columns in your DataGrid (using VS is pretty simple with the designer) and then you can use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Object.Length; i++)
    dataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Object[i];
```

In this case i'm using Cells[0], but you can specify any cell on your row to put the values.

Comment: I have three `DataGridTextColumns`. I'm not sure how to implement your code. No such properties for Rows, Cells, or Value exist.

Comment: @user2722800, `DataGrid`, in WPF, has no `Rows` or `Cells`

Comment: My bad, guess I didn't spot that detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind your listbox to the DataGrid something like:

```
<Window x:Class="Bind02.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Bind02" Height="300" Width="300"
>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Click="OnLoad">_Load</Button>
            <Button Click="OnSave">_Save</Button>
            <Button Click="OnAdd">_Add</Button>
            <Button Click="OnEdit">_Edit</Button>
            <Button Click="OnDelete">_Delete</Button>
            <Button Click="OnExit">E_xit</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
object[] AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().ToArray();
```

use

```
List<string> AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().ToList();
MyDataGrid.ItemSource = Allfiles;
```

This will automatically bind the files to the DataGrid.

Comment: I have tried this before posting. This results in an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.IO.FileInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Answer (score -1):

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();

foreach (string file in fileEntries)
{

fileList.Add(new FileInfo(file));
}

datagrid.ItemsSource = fileList;
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon in SO. Please add some explanation for the benefit of others reading your code!