# How to display datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm reading a word document using interop line by line. Now I want the lines to be displayed on a data grid which is in XAML code.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Text");


for (int i = 0; i < doc.Sentences.Count; i++)
{
    //string temp = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.Trim();
    string temp = doc.Sentences[i + 1].Text;
    if (temp != string.Empty)
    {
        data.Add(temp);
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { data });
    }
}
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474761/list-directory-files-in-a-datagrid) might help.....

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your data context returning your DataTable (assuming your datacontext implements INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
    private DataTable _aTable;
    public DataTable aTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _aTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _aTable= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("aTable");
        }
    }
```

Then in your xaml for the datagrid bind ItemSource to your dataTable property:

```
    <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="true" ItemsSource="{Binding aTable}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare dataGrid in XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"/>
```

and once your DataTable is filled you can set its `DataView` as `ItemsSource` of DataGrid:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

**OR**

Declare property in proper ViewModel of type `DataTable` and bind to it.

Comment: It's not working.Throwing exception input array is longer than the columns in the table.System.argumentException

Comment: That exception already existing in your code i guess at this line `dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { data });`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind the Datatable to the Grid's ItemsSource and set AutoGeneratColumns as "true".

[XAML]

```
<DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="true" ItemsSource="{Binding dt}">
```

[c#]

```
private DataTable _dt;
public DataTable dt
{
    get
    {
        return _dt;
    }
    set
    {
        _dt= value;
    }
}

Void Load()
{
  dt.Columns.Add("Text");

  for (int i = 0; i < doc.Sentences.Count; i++)
  {
    string temp = doc.Sentences[i + 1].Text;
    if (temp != string.Empty)
    { 
      data.Add(temp);
      dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { data });
    } 
  }
}
```