# How to show file in gridview based on specific file name from folder in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to ask about gridview by using Asp.Net. I want to show my uploaded data(doc,xls,ppt,pdf) in gridview based on specific name of the file. So the scenario if the file contains name SOP_IT.doc it will show in Gridview for SOP_IT, if the file contains name SOP_FAT.doc it will show in Gridview for SOP_FAT. So, I have a few gridview to display files according the file name.
Please help me solve this.
Thank you :)
This my code in Page_Load:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Forms/UploadFile/"))
        Dim files As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)
        For Each filePath As String In filePaths
            files.Add(New ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath))
        Next
        gvFileDetails.DataSource = files
        gvFileDetails.DataBind()
    End If
```

From this code above, i can display the file in that Folder but how can i display the file in that folder in Gridview by specific file name?

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474761/list-directory-files-in-a-datagrid

Comment: i have read it and i still confuse. would you like to write the code? I make this in my web app.

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. But you need to use `Path`: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Comment: btw u could use ´DataGrid´ not gridview, maybe this term will help u on ur google search

Comment: @Joinnes pls update  ur original post with ur code, not here in the comments ^^

Comment: Please Help....